# InputScope="Number" on PasswordBox

Tags: .net, windows, xaml

I can't find the InputScope="Number" on passwordbox on xaml, i need force a numeric pad on passwordbox. I'm using the new sdk for windows 8 and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can't do it directly, you'll have to create a custom control, or just use a TextBox with a custom KeyUp event.

There's an example here for Windows Phone 8 : http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_a_PasswordBox_with_numeric_Input_Scope_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: Was helpful:  my source stays:  _enteredPasscode = textBox.Text.ToString();
                    texboxPin.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_enteredPasscode, @".", _passwordChar);
                    pwboxPin.Text += _enteredPasscode.Replace(_passwordChar, @"");
                    texboxPin.Select(texboxPin.Text.Length, 0);